# How to download API demos in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

There are several guides on Android that refer to `<sdk_root>/ApiDemos/`. I checked it but the directory was empty. I opened SDK Manager in Android Studio and looked up the tabs for SDK Platforms and SDK Tools, but there was nothing like "API Demos". Searching online, I didn't find any article on this. There is also a page on Android.com: https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html, which seems to house all the demos.  Is there a way I can download all SDK demos in Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option in Android Studio (confirmed on v3.1.1) to download samples:

**Files -> New -> Import Sample...**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/tree/master/samples/ApiDemos

I would recommend below source codes also:

https://github.com/search?q=org%3Agooglesamples+android